# Populate a Managed Metadata field with jquery

Tags: managed-metadata, spservices

I'm using a managed metadata field in a list to represent X properties. I'm using a column site to do this.

In a document Library Z I'm using the same column site and a field Y that contains values from X list, If i select an X value i want to populate my managed metadata field in Z with the value I have on X List.

How can I do this? I'm using SPServices and i'm getting the managed metadata field value for X but i don't know how to set this value in Z

Comment: Could you include your code and a screenshot of the form?